# Probleme with javascript error (--unhandled-rejections=strict)

Tags: javascript

i'm learning javascript and i'm stuck with the following error: --unhandled-rejections = strict i'm breaking my head i can't get by. here is the part of my code that blocks me

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

//REGISTER
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const newUser = new User({
  username: req.body.username,
  email: req.body.email,
  password: req.body.password,
});
try {
  const user = await newUser.save();
  req.statusCode(201).json(user);
} catch (err) {
 res.status(500).json({
      message: err,
  });
 }
});

module.exports = router;
```

here is the error message I receive when
I run my request in postman.
I use the post method and in postman I have no results
i used npm run --unhandled-rejections = strict in my terminal but i had no contrary effect i still have the same message

```
 [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
app listening on port 8800!
MongoDB connected
(node:3508) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read 
property 'username' of undefined
at C:\Users\Philippe\Desktop\projets\reat- 
netflix\api\routes\auth.js:9:24
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
 (C:\Users\Philippe\Desktop\projets\reat- 
netflix\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\Philippe\Desktop\projets\reat- 
netflix\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Philippe\Desktop\projets\reat- 
netflix\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request
(C:\Users\Philippe\Desktop\projets\reat- 
netflix\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
   at C:\Users\Philippe\Desktop\projets\reat- 
netflix\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Philippe\Desktop\projets\reat- 
netflix\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\Philippe\Desktop\projets\reat- 
netflix\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (C:\Users\Philippe\Desktop\projets\reat- 
netflix\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
 at router (C:\Users\Philippe\Desktop\projets\reat- 
netflix\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 


(C:\Users\Philippe\Desktop\projets\reat- 
netflix\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Philippe\Desktop\projets\reat- 
netflix\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at C:\Users\Philippe\Desktop\projets\reat- 
netflix\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Philippe\Desktop\projets\reat- 
netflix\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\Philippe\Desktop\projets\reat- 
netflix\api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at expressInit (C:\Users\Philippe\Desktop\projets\reat- 
netflix\api\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3508) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise 
rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async 
function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not 
 handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled 
 promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` 
 (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). 
 (rejection id: 1)
 (node:3508) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections 
 are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled  
will 
terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: What is the error text? Do you see any output at all?

Comment: Maybe 'res...'  instead 'req.statusCode(201).json(user);'

Comment: always the same

Comment: The error is actually `TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined` which means `req.body` is undefined. Are you sending a body with the post request? How do you access this endpoint?

Comment: yes I send a body with the post method the data is in json and in raw

Comment: Not according to the error?

Comment: i finally found the error. It was a bad place in my index file, Thanks for your help

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I had placed the app.use (express.json ()); in the wrong place

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the unhandled rejection, i.e. to handle the error, you need to put the first statement of your request handler in the `try` block as well:

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
    });
    const user = await newUser.save();
    req.statusCode(201).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: err,
    });
  }
});
```

To prevent the error itself, you probably need to fix your middleware that populates `req.body`.